# rbac authorization check in Yii doesn't work (Getting unknown property: app\models\Post::createdBy)

Tags: yii, yii2, rbac

I looked at the documentation for rbac in Yii and thought I understood how it worked until I actually tried it.

This is the rule for checking whether the author of the post is trying to get the authorization for an action:

```
class AuthorRule extends Rule
{
    public $name = 'isAuthor';

    /**
     * @param string|integer $user the user ID.
     * @param Item $item the role or permission that this rule is associated with
     * @param array $params parameters passed to ManagerInterface::checkAccess().
     * @return boolean a value indicating whether the rule permits the role or permission it is associated with.
     */
    public function execute($user, $item, $params)
    {
        return isset($params['model']) ? $params['model']->createdBy == $user : false;
    }
}
```

This is how I am trying to use the rule and Yii's rbac:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if (\Yii::$app->user->can('update', ['model' => $model])) {




        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get this when I try to edit a Post:

```
Getting unknown property: app\models\Post::createdBy
```

So I thought I had to replace createdBy with userId which is a column in the table Post and I am getting a blank page meaning it doesn't work. So I am trying to guess what $user is.

I also tried:

```
return isset($params['model']) ? $params['model']->userId == $user->id : false;
```

and I am getting: `Trying to get property of non-object.`

What should I do to make it work? The doc seemed to suggest you just had to plug the conditional inside the controller action to make it work, but it doesn't seem to be the case at all.

var dump:

```
object(app\models\Post)[75]
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'userId' => int 1
      'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'content' => string 'lol' (length=3)
      'dateCreated' => null
      'dateUpdated' => null
  private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 1
      'userId' => int 1
      'title' => string 'test' (length=4)
      'content' => string 'lol' (length=3)
      'dateCreated' => null
      'dateUpdated' => null
  private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_errors' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_validators' (yii\base\Model) => null
  private '_scenario' (yii\base\Model) => string 'default' (length=7)
  private '_events' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_behaviors' (yii\base\Component) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty

null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error says, that you don't have a `createdBy` property in your `Post` model. Do you?

The second error is about trying to get a property of non-object variable. Could you show `var_dump($params['model']); var_dump($user);` before the return?

Comment: how do I output a var_dump or where do I get the output of var_dump?

Comment: Put var dumps before `return isset($params['model']) ? $params['model']->userId == $user->id : false;`

Comment: added the output to the question

Comment: I use a class called Member instead of the default User.

Comment: I tried it again, but it seems to work. Maybe, I didn't test it properly the first time. LOL... I think I might have forgot to log in or something.

Comment: I noticed that user is equal to int 2, is that normal? I had to change $user->id to $user. It worked for my first user, but for the second one it didn't work, so I changed it and now it works for both. Strange.

Comment: Yes, it's expected. See the PHPDoc of the execute method in yii\rbac\Rule